# How to put mutual exclusive method in dictionary in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scraper

i am writing a scraper to extract the content of different sites. User inputs an url, my scraper would parse the url and find out which source does it come from (it only supports limited website) and extract the content according to the website's dom structure.

The easiest way looks like this:

```
extract(soup, url):

  if url in siteA:
    content = soup.find_all('p')[0]
  elif url in siteB:
    content = soup.find_all('p')[3]
  elif url in siteC:
    content = soup.find_all('div', {'id':'ChapterBody'})[0]
  elif url in siteD:
    content = soup.find_all("td", {"class": "content"})[0]
```

However the code is redundant as there are more sites with different rules coming, so I would like to compact the code and make it easier. Here is the way i tried:

```
extract(soup, url):

  support = {
            'siteA': soup.find_all('p')[0]
            'siteB': soup.find_all('p')[3]
            'siteC': soup.find_all('div', {'id':'ChapterBody'})[0]
            'siteD': soup.find_all("td", {"class": "content"})[0]
            }

  if url in support:
    content = support[url]
```

In this way I only need to keeping track of a dictionary rather than keep appending the code. **However, each key value pair is being executed when i run the code, and index error is showed because some sites does not have a 'td' or 'div' with id 'chapterbody'**, so error would be raised when siteC/D in dictionary get executed.

I am wondering what are some possible ways to solve this issue while keep the code compact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the dictionary over to a dict of functions:

```
support = {
          'siteA': lambda: soup.find_all('p')[0],
          'siteB': lambda: soup.find_all('p')[3],
          'siteC': lambda: soup.find_all('div', {'id':'ChapterBody'})[0],
          'siteD': lambda: soup.find_all("td", {"class": "content"})[0]
          }
```

Now they don't execute until you call the function:

```
if url in support:
    content = support[url]()
```

---

Alternatively, pulling out the `soup.find_all()` call and having a dictionary of tuples (param, index) is also an option:

```
support = {
          'siteA': (('p'), 0),
          'siteB': (('p'), 3),
          'siteC': (('div', {'id':'ChapterBody'}), 0),
          'siteD': (("td", {"class": "content"}), 0)
          }

if url in support:
    param, index = support[url]
    content = soup.findall(*param)[index]
```

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is that the code that you've written to extract the content, eg `soup.find_all('p')[0]`, is being executed immediately when `support` is created, which makes sense.. you are asking python to assign the return value of `soup.find_all('p')[0]` to a dictionary value, and it is doing that.. and so on for all the other entries.

What you intended to do is to store a function that you can execute when you are ready.. and for that, you can use a lambda function:

```
support = {
    'siteA': lambda s: s.find_all('p')[0],
    'siteB': lambda s: s.find_all('p')[3],
}

if url in support:
    content = support[url](soup)
```

But maybe one day you'll have a site where the code to extract the content is more complicated and it can't be expressed in a lambda function (which only supports one expression).  So in that case you could use a nested function:

```
def site_complicated(s):
    # this is not complicated.. but it could be...
    return s.find_all('p')[0]

support = {
    'siteA': lambda s: s.find_all('p')[0],
    'siteB': lambda s: s.find_all('p')[3],
    'siteComplicated': site_complicated,
}
```